# DateTime.ToString("g") fr_CA

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

There is an aberration with date formatting using fr_CA culture.

`DateTime.ToString("g")` returns "YYYY-MM-DD 00:00" format because "YYYY-MM-DD" is the official Canada date format.
The problem is that this format is not used at all neither by francophones and anglophones !!

So my question is: is there a way to bypass the default implementation of `DateTime.ToString(string format)` so that I can use "dd/mm/yyyy" instead for fr_CA which corresponds to the real usage ? and the default implementation for all other cultures.

And is it possible to do it without using another method name ?

Comment: Please read, this may answer your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: im afraid you will have to handle that yourself.

Comment: Side note: please avoid tags in the title and thank you notes in your post.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but why not `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` ??

Comment: You can use `fr-FR` ;)

Comment: Thomas: Good idea, that what I did temporarily but i feared that it could do other things i don't want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this on a case by case basis. If the culture is `fr-CA`, replace it with a modified copy when your app starts:

```
if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "fr-CA")
{
    var frca = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    frca.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = frca;
}
```

And do the same for any culture you need to "customize".

Note that new threads will still start with the system-defined culture; if you're using .NET 4.5 or later, you can override that behavior using the `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` property:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = frca;
```